# Save PDF from Excel with same format using Excel Interop

Tags: c#, excel, pdf, excel-interop

I have a problem when saving from Excel to a PDF. The formatting changes from one computer to the next.

Before saving to PDF, I set the following format in Excel: Page Break is A4, Margin is 1.3 on all sides, and Orientation is Landscape.

Then I use command `excelWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat` to export to PDF,
but the PDF format is different on other computers.

On computer A, I have the PDF file with full A4 page in the correct format. On computer B, I have more than one A4 page. On computer C, I have one A4 page but the margin is incorrect.

How do I save the PDF to have the same format on any machine using the Excel Interop?